# Sending/Receiving binary data in Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

It seems `bytestring` is not a serializable instance in `aeson` which might be sensible thing to do according these tickets under `aeson github tracker`:  [ticket1](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/126), [ticket2](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/187).

So, what is good way to serialize/deserialize binary objects in `aeson` then? This is what `MDN` seems to recommend for serializing binary objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data.

**Update**

Looking at the `JSON` [source code](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types/Instances.hs#L432), I see `Word8` is a valid instance. So, would it be best to just send the bytearray as `Vector` of `Word8` from Javascript ([`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array))?

Comment: Generally speaking, binary is not compatible with JSON (i.e. your binary data could mangle your JSON by adding extraneous delimiting characters such as `"`, `'`, `{`, etc.). You should consider using an algorithm such as [base64](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring) to first convert your binary to an ASCII format if you want to transmit this data over a plain-text format (such as JSON).

Comment: @RageD, if there is a simple example of how to do that using Aeson, that will be very helpful. You could put it as an answer. I am guessing one could send it over the wire as `Text`, and in `Aeson` decoder, first convert `Text` to `ByteString` using `encodeUTF8`, and then do `decode` in `base64` to get back original binary data. Not sure if I got this right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for an example on base64-encoding your data to send over JSON, I have whipped up a crude example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main(main) where
import qualified Control.Applicative as App
import qualified Data.Aeson as A
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
import Data.ByteString.Base64
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Encoding

data MyObject = MyObject { objectName :: Text, objectData :: ByteString } deriving (Eq)

instance FromJSON ByteString where
  parseJSON (String t) = pure $ (either (const "") id . decode . encodeUtf8) t
  parseJSON _ = App.empty

instance ToJSON ByteString where
  toJSON = String . decodeUtf8 . encode

instance FromJSON MyObject where
  parseJSON (Object v) = MyObject <$> v .: "name" <*> v .: "data"
  parseJSON _ = App.empty

instance ToJSON MyObject where
  toJSON obj = object [ "name" .= objectName obj, "data" .= objectData obj ]

exampleObject :: MyObject
exampleObject = MyObject "example" "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"

exampleJson :: LB.ByteString
exampleJson = "{\"data\":\"AQIDBAU=\",\"name\":\"example\"}"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ A.encode exampleObject
  print $ exampleObject == fromMaybe (MyObject "fail" "") (A.decode exampleJson)
```

Which should produce the following output:

```
"{\"data\":\"AQIDBAU=\",\"name\":\"example\"}"
True
```

To be a little more explicit, the real magic happens in our definitions of `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` for `ByteString`:

```
instance FromJSON ByteString where
  parseJSON (String t) = pure $ (either (const "") id . decode . encodeUtf8) t
  parseJSON _ = App.empty

instance ToJSON ByteString where
  toJSON = String . decodeUtf8 . encode
```

In short, this provides Aeson direction on how we want it to Serialize any instance of the (strict) `ByteString` type. Now any instance of `ByteString` encountered will be automatically encoded and decoded as we have specified (notice how `MyObject` looks like a "typical" Aeson defintion). Of course, if you only wanted to encode **particular** `ByteString`s, you could forgo the `instance` definitions and do it right there in the code for `MyObject` serialization.

The `ToJSON` simply calls the `encode` from the base64 library on the input and converts the resulting `ByteString` (from the `encode` call) to a `Text` object which is the input the `String` constructor takes (a type of Aeson `Value` which must be returned from this function).

The `FromJSON` looks a little bit scarier, but-- in principle-- is quite similar. We take the Aeson `Value` of type `String` (for anything else we return `empty`) and we convert the `Text` value contained within the `String` object to a `ByteString`. We then feed this `ByteString` to the base64 `decode` method which produces an `Either` (depending on whether or not it could successfully decode the `ByteString`). We simply return an empty string in the case where this failed, otherwise we provide the decoded value to the object.

The main function serves as a simple sanity check. I first encode `exampleObject` (containing a 5-byte binary string) and print its value. On the following line, we take that output and have called it `exampleJson`. We decode `exampleJson` and compare it to the memory which we had constructed in memory. These values are-- as expected-- equal to each other so you can see that encoding and decoding is working properly.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful!

Comment: Indeed a very helpful post